# SerializeToString dosn't work as expected protobuf c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm using Qt Creator 12.0.2
Based on Qt 6.6.0 (GCC 10.3.1 20210422 (Red Hat 10.3.1-1), x86_64).

I want to serialize a structure with a method `SerializeToString`. I have data.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message DiagnosticData {
    string velocity = 1;
    int32 transmission = 2;
    float transportWeight = 3;
    float tirePresure = 4;
};
```

I have a method where I test how the structure is serialized:

```
void Client::SendDiagnosticData() {

    std::string* buf = new std::string;
    std::string* buf2 = new std::string;
    DiagnosticData dData = GenerateDiagnosticData();
    DiagnosticData dData2;
    dData.SerializeToString(buf);

    dData2.ParseFromString(buf->c_str());
    dData2.SerializeToString(buf2);

    qDebug() << "1: " << *buf;
    qDebug() << "2: " << *buf2;


    delete buf;
    delete buf2;
}
```

GenerateDiagnosticData a function that fills data with random values:

```
DiagnosticData GenerateDiagnosticData() {

    DiagnosticData dData;
    int vel = rand() % 55 + 1;
    int trsmn = rand() % 2 + 1;
    int w = rand() % 60 + 1;
    int pres = rand() % 10 + 1;


    dData.set_velocity(std::to_string(vel));
    dData.set_transmission(trsmn);
    dData.set_transportweight(w);
    dData.set_tirepresure(pres);


    return dData;
}
```

In a function `SendDiagnosticData`, I serialize the structure, then I deserialize it into a new structure and see if they are the same, but as it turns out, the second structure is only a part of the first, here’s a screenshot:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS5oo.png)

Initially, `message DiagnosticData` `velocity` was `float`, and then the symbol (/r) was written into the new structure and that’s it, and after changing it to string it started to show at least something

Comment: `ParseFromString` will stop at the first NUL byte.

Comment: @Botje How can I avoid this other than making all variables strings?

Comment: Don't pass `buf->c_str()`, just pass `buf`. Because a `std::string` knows its length while a `char*` does not.

Comment: @Botje Should I use char* instead of string?

Comment: No, you should pass a `std::string`. In your case this is `*buf`. Also, you should strongly reconsider switching to plain `std::string`s instead of pointers.